# error trying to import some spatial analysis libraries in jupyter notebook: ImportError: DLL load failed: El sistema operativo no puede ejecutar %1

Tags: jupyter, importerror, geopandas

I'm trying to run this code on jupyter notebook to work with geopandas for making geospatial analysis:

```py
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, pandas as pd, geopandas as gpd
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from shapely.geometry import Point
from geopy.distance import great_circle
```

this is the error message I got after run the code:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-987457051b80> in <module>
      1 # import necessary modules
----> 2 import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, pandas as pd, geopandas as gpd
      3 from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
      4 from shapely.geometry import Point
      5 from geopy.distance import great_circle

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\geopandas\__init__.py in <module>
      2 from geopandas.geodataframe import GeoDataFrame
      3 
----> 4 from geopandas.io.file import read_file
      5 from geopandas.io.sql import read_postgis
      6 from geopandas.tools import sjoin

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py in <module>
      1 import os
      2 
----> 3 import fiona
      4 import numpy as np
      5 import six

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py in <module>
     81     os.environ["PATH"] = os.environ["PATH"] + ";" + libdir
     82 
---> 83 from fiona.collection import BytesCollection, Collection
     84 from fiona.drvsupport import supported_drivers
     85 from fiona.env import ensure_env_with_credentials, Env

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py in <module>
      7 
      8 from fiona import compat, vfs
----> 9 from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator
     10 from fiona.ogrext import Session, WritingSession
     11 from fiona.ogrext import buffer_to_virtual_file, remove_virtual_file, GEOMETRY_TYPES

ImportError: DLL load failed: El sistema operativo no puede ejecutar %1.
```

Can you provide any help?

Comment: Can you some details on how you installed `geopandas` ?

Comment: I don't remember well but I guess from the command prompt pasting:

conda install -c conda-forge geopandas

Comment: If not I wrote directly in the command prompt from:
    C:\Users\myaccount>conda install geopy shapely basemap geopandas

Comment: Can you try to create a new environment with `conda create -n geo_env geopandas`, and see if that works?

Comment: Thank you very much @joris it woked :)
Does it means that it would worked as well if would reinstall Anaconda?

Comment: Not sure, but possibly.